# How to do web scraping for dynamic website

Tags: web

I would like parse below website in javascript.
https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm

I tried different frameworks for web scraping like PhantomJS,Osmosis,JSDOM but did not get success.
Can anyone please help me out.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried nightmareJs? https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare

Comment: Sure.will try nightmare.js.thank you.